# Xcode - Show ad every x times view appears

Tags: ios, xcode, viewwillappear

i have implemented the AdMob frameworks and make it work so it gets displayed but i need to have the ad displayed every 3 times a view appears and i am stuck.

EDIT: 
`@property (nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;`

What i have so far:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];


static long int counter = 1;



NSLog(@"Before: %ld", counter);

if ([self.interstitial isReady] && !(counter++ % 3)) {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];

    counter = 1;
    NSLog(@"After increase : %ld", counter);
}

}
```

The problem is every time the Ad is shown, the counter increases 2 times which means the Ad is shown odd times.

Comment: There's no reason why `-viewWillAppear:` should be causing the counter to be increased by 2 unless the view is about to appear... twice...

Comment: It does as the ad disappears, the view will appear again for the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try declaring `counter` as a global variable:

```
int counter;
```

And then do something such as:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    if ([self.interstitial isReady] && counter >= 3) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        counter++;
        NSLog(@"After increase : %d", counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this seems to show an Ad every single time the view appears. I was thinking more like every 3 times my view appears

Comment: Which part is responsible for showing the ad, I wasn't sure — and how are you determining the frequency for non-ad views? Like when you say that it should show every three times the view is shown then it should be an easy fix i think.

Comment: Oh the `viewWillAppear` method above is in the front page of my app, on my front page there is a `Play Game` button in that game you have 3 lives and when you have 0 lives left that view controller is popped off my navigation stack. and back to front page. (Is this what you meant?)

Comment: Yeah. So what you mean is that for every three non-ad views there should be one view that has the ad?

Comment: Yeah only my front page will show Ads - edit: (hopefully every 3 times it is shown after game)

Comment: Check the edit, and see if that is more what you're thinking.

Comment: Yes this seems to work, sorry for not responding fast had a little error to fix first :) thanks